# SSIS package: permissions

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm fairly certain at this point that my trouble is rooted in permissions.

My SSIS package simply pulls data from an Access DB and populates a SQL table. When I run this package in VS (by clicking Start), it works and my SQL table populates. As soon as I try to execute the package within SSMS or in a SQL Agent job, it falls apart, with the following errors:

[image]

I am running SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server Data Tools in VS 2013, in case that is relevant information.

Great appreciation for anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you run the package in 32-bit mode in SSMS?

Comment: I wasn't aware there was an option for that. Is this a reference to selecting '32-bit runtime' in the Validate... selection after right-clicking on the package?

Comment: Yes, it is, like the error message suggests.

Comment: Ok, I tried this, but same errors persist.

Comment: Are those drivers installed server side where the package is deployed?

Comment: It could also be network path-related.   Maybe you can get to the access database from your local computer, but not from the SSIS server.

Comment: I believe they are. However, I think I may have accidentally stumbled upon the problem. My SQL Server 2016 is 64 bit, but my Access is 32 bit. That's a problem, right?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with it. What does is whether you have dirvers of appropriate bitness installed. You don't need to guess, go to the "ODBC" in the Control panel (32 and 64 bits separately) and see what is available under "User DSN", "System DSN" and "Drivers" in each.

Comment: I went to the server where my SQL is hosted and found both the 32 and 64 bit ODBC Admin boxes. The User DSN and System DSN is blank for both, and the Drivers tab has numerous entries on both, but I don't understand what I'm really looking at. I'll start looking into this, but if you have any specific input, I would love to hear it! Thank you!

Comment: You are looking for the driver that your package is using. From the error message, it is using the OLE DB Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. Do you have that driver on the Drivers tab in 32 and 64 bits? If your connection string is also using a DSN, you are looking for that DSN to be present on the DSN tab.

Comment: So since my Access is 32-bit and my SQL Server is 64 bit, would that necessitate that I create an ODBC with the 32 or 64 bit connection? Or do I need both? Sorry, I'm really not clear on how this works with the differing versions.